# How to set Visual Studio Code formatting for Java to Allman style?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I've been using VSCode for a while, and it bothers me that it constantly changes my code from my preferred style (Allman) to something else (I think K&R, not really sure). I end up using that type of formatting in JS and TS, since I've read it can save you from problems later, but I like to keep my Java classes as Allman. Does anyone know how to set the default Java formatter to Allman on VSCode?